# OpenGL ES 2.0 Trouble implementing the standard linear fog function

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've been trying to implement a basic fog function, and some resources I've found have led me to try a linear fog function that my understanding has led me to believe is based on the original fixed function fog equation (though I could be wrong on that). However, when I try to implement it, all my surfaces become black. I'm pretty sure my problem lies in how I (attempt to) compute the eye distance, as the rest of the equation is pretty straightforward.

My vertex shader:

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 texCoordIn;

varying vec3 eyeNormal;
varying vec4 eyePos;
varying vec2 texCoordOut;
varying float eyeDistance;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

void main()
{
    eyeNormal = (normalMatrix * normal);
    eyePos = modelViewMatrix * position;      
    eyeDistance = sqrt((eyePos.x - cameraPosition.x) * (eyePos.x - cameraPosition.x) + (eyePos.y - cameraPosition.y) * (eyePos.y - cameraPosition.y) + (eyePos.z - cameraPosition.z) * (eyePos.z - cameraPosition.z));
    texCoordOut = texCoordIn;
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

My fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 eyeNormal;
varying vec4 eyePos;
varying vec2 texCoordOut;
varying float eyeDistance;
uniform sampler2D texture;

uniform vec3 flashlightPosition;
uniform vec3 diffuseLightPosition;
uniform vec4 diffuseComponent;
uniform float shininess;
uniform vec4 specularComponent;
uniform vec4 ambientComponent;
uniform float maxFogDistance;
uniform float minFogDistance;
uniform vec4 fogColor;

void main()

{
    vec4 ambient = ambientComponent;

    vec3 N = normalize(eyeNormal);
    float nDotVP = max(0.0, dot(N, normalize(diffuseLightPosition)));
    vec4 diffuse = diffuseComponent * nDotVP;

    vec3 E = normalize(-eyePos.xyz);
    vec3 L = normalize(flashlightPosition - eyePos.xyz);
    vec3 H = normalize(L+E);
    float Ks = pow(max(dot(N, H), 0.0), shininess);
    vec4 specular = Ks*specularComponent;
    if( dot(L, N) < 0.0 ) {
        specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    float factor = (maxFogDistance - eyeDistance) / (maxFogDistance - minFogDistance);
    factor = clamp(factor, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 finalFogColor = factor * fogColor;

    vec4 finalColor = (ambient + specular) * texture2D(texture, texCoordOut);
    gl_FragColor = finalColor * factor + fogColor * (1.0 - factor);
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

Additionally, the minimum fog distance has been set to 1f and the maximum to 10f (my movement space is quite small, currently 5x5, so this should be appropriate) and the fog color is set to white.

Any help anybody could provide would be much appreciated. I can post additional code if the problem isn't in the shaders (though, I can't figure anywhere else it would be, the other aspects of the shaders worked fine before this).

Comment: The eye distance is most definitely wrong. I honestly can not see what you tried to do there. I think you should include the uniform for the eye position, next this "eyePos = modelViewMatrix * position;" is not an eye position but a vertex position. So then you need to find the distance between the eye position (the uniform one) and the vertex position (currently called eyePos). The current equation has some really unexpected situations, for instance if your model matrix is identity the distance will always be zero.

Comment: Reading your comment made me realize a mistake I made. I was confusing the position in my shader with my camera/eye position (also called position, but in my main code). Yeah, that was really dumb. But, passing the camera position in as a uniform and putting that in the equation didn't fix it. See my new vertex code.

Comment: Ok, so looking at your fragment shader you only add the fogColor part to the original color which you claim it used to work. Could you try to just remove the  "+ fogColor * (1.0 - factor)" part from your shader and confirm you receive the appropriate result as I can not see how this code could produce a black color. Another issue might be the shader not compiling. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No compile errors. Taking out the "+ fogColor * (1.0 - factor)" still produces the black colour. Also removed the "* factor" and just ran my initial lighting calculations to confirm that I didn't break something along the way. The original results still work correctly.

Comment: So if you only use "gl_FragColor = finalColor" it works as it should?

Comment: Then I guess more could be wrong... Let us test the factor first: Use gl_FragColor = vec4(factor, factor, factor,1.0). This should produce a nice grayscale image. If you see only one color then the factor is not correct. Next try to only draw the fog color gl_FragColor = fogColor to check if the fog color is indeed white as you claim. Please report the results.

Comment: I apologize, I figured it out. I had accidentally typed glUniform3fv instead of glUniform4fv when passing in the fog colour. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: You have nothing to apologize for. I could not find the issue you have created with the data you posted but using these simple procedures I guided you through did help you find it yourself. The problem when working with OpenGL is there are too many places to make a small mistake that will completely break your code. Knowing how to pinpoint the issue is more valuable then simply finding the issue by mistake. I hope you learned something about that today and try it yourself next time.